# AWS ELB health check fails all the time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I am trying to run my .net core project on aws fargate but I always keep getting unhealthy responses from my ELB. I looked at all the previous answers and check everything but I could not see what I am missing.

Please someone help me because I'll totally lose my mind. I have done it before successfully but this time it does not run.

I have created two new subnets and created an ELB on that subnets also my fargate services and task run on the same subnet. my security group rules seem ok. I also get a successful response when I try to reach my health endpoint from the browser by using a public IP address that the task gave me.

Please see the screenshots and show me a way to achieve that.

Here are my container logs to show that it is up and running

[image]

This is my load balancer subnet

[image]

Fargate service subnets

[image]

Task subnet

[image]

Security Group rules

[image]

Here is the unhealthy result

[image]

Health Check settings

[image]

The public and local IP address that the task generates

[image]

This is the response from the health check endpoint from the browser
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I have noticed that my app is listening on port 80. I have updated my docker file to listen on port 8080. and it still fails on health check

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. I am not sure what the reason is but I have created from scratch all target groups with HTTP1 as HTTP protocol.

Formerly It was HTTP2. Somehow HTTP2 was not worked. Everything else remained the same. I just deleted my HTTP2 target groups and created an HTTP1 target group. After that, it worked perfectly.

[image]